# Set a title bar gradient in an android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-drawable

I want to set a gradient on my application title bar (from `#F55B53` to `#FFFF00`), with this following code :

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {0xF55B53,0xFFFF00});
View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
titleBar.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

But eclipse tell me :

> The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) from the type view is
>   deprecated

What I should do?

Comment: Which title are you trying to modify?

Comment: The main title bar, the title which is placed at the top of the screen by default, when you create the project

Comment: That title bar is old, if you are creating a new app you might want to use an Action Bar. Check ActionBarSherlock: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time you get a deprecation warning, it comes along with the correct way of doing it.
If you go to the [View class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), you will notice that the `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)` method says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 16. use
>   setBackground(Drawable) instead

Depending on the android version you are targeting you might want to continue using the deprecated one.

Comment: Thanks.. but now eclipse tell me that this call requires API level 16 (and my current min is API level 11)...

Comment: Ok, that's because the `setBackground(Drawable)` is not there in API level 11. Just use the deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

titleBar.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

change the code

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable()
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```